# Combining two files using python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, for-loop, valueerror

I use pycharm version 2.7.9 and pandas version - 0.19.2.
I have a csv file called - 'data' that contains data of station name with latitudes and longitudes.

```
df = pd.read_csv(data.csv, sep="^", dtype=object)
df["train_board_station"] = ['Tokyo','LA','Paris','New_York','Delhi']
df["train_off_station"] = ['Phoenix','London','Sydney','Berlin','Shanghai']
```

I take another csv file in which if the 'train_board_station' and 'train_off_station' is same as 'station', then latitude and longitude data is added to it.

```
ref = pd.read_csv(ref.csv, sep="^", header=0, dtype=str)
df["station"] = ['Tokyo','London','Paris','New_York','Shanghai,''LA','Sydney','Berlin','Phoenix','Delhi']
df["latitude"] = ['-34.54','56.789','-78,98','45.62','111.67','23.78','-98.40','-76.89','23.98','23.89']
df["longitude"] = ['34.89','-78.55','78.89','34.12','56.56','23.23','-78.65','34.76','23.67','21.645']
```

I would like to merge 'latitude' and 'longitude' from 'ref.csv' file if the 'train_board_station', 'train_off_station' matches with 'station' in the data.csv

```
for x in ["board", "off"]:
    df["station"] = df["train_" + x + "_station"]
    df = pd.concat([df, ref], axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])
    df[x + "_latitude"] = df["latitude"]
    df[x + "_longitude"] = df["longitude"]
```

When I try to run the code. I get the error as -

```
  KeyError: 'train_board_station'
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: yes. i have added. plz check the code

Comment: That error seems pretty clear - `df` has no key `'train_board_station'`.

Comment: I am beginner in coding, can you explain me in detail ?

Comment: Try to print out `df.keys()` both before and after the `pd.concat` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["train_board_station"] = ['Tokyo','LA','Paris','New_York','Delhi']
df["train_off_station"] = ['Phoenix','London','Sydney','Berlin','Shanghai']

#need ref DataFrame
ref = pd.DataFrame()
ref["station"] = ['Tokyo','London','Paris','New_York','Shanghai','LA','Sydney','Berlin','Phoenix','Delhi']
ref["latitude"] = ['-34.54','56.789','-78,98','45.62','111.67','23.78','-98.40','-76.89','23.98','23.89']
ref["longitude"] = ['34.89','-78.55','78.89','34.12','56.56','23.23','-78.65','34.76','23.67','21.645']
```

I believe you can use  [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) in loop:

```
for x in ["board", 'off']:
    val = "train_" + x + "_station"
    df1 = df[[val]].join(ref.set_index('station'), on=val)
    df[x + "_latitude"] = df1["latitude"]
    df[x + "_longitude"] = df1["longitude"]
print (df)
  train_board_station train_off_station board_latitude board_longitude  \
0               Tokyo           Phoenix         -34.54           34.89   
1                  LA            London          23.78           23.23   
2               Paris            Sydney         -78,98           78.89   
3            New_York            Berlin          45.62           34.12   
4               Delhi          Shanghai          23.89          21.645   

  off_latitude off_longitude  
0        23.98         23.67  
1       56.789        -78.55  
2       -98.40        -78.65  
3       -76.89         34.76  
4       111.67         56.56
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Check column names `print (ref.columns.tolist())` and `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: I think there are some whitespaces, thn is possible use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` for remove it.

Comment: you are right!!!!! one of the file is missing the column names !! whoa ! thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the `.join` function. First a minimal setup.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "station": ["Tokyo", "Amsterdam"],
    "size": [100, 200]
})

ref = pd.DataFrame({
    "train_station": ["Amsterdam", "Tokyo"],
    "lon": [23, 12],
    "lat": [34, 12]
})
```

The key to joining is setting the index on both dataframes.

```
df.set_index("station").join(ref.set_index("train_station"))
```

**Out**

[image]